# How to edit my git origin? fatal: protocol 'git@https' is not supported

Tags: git

```
git push -u origin master
```

shows

```
fatal: protocol 'git@https' is not supported

git remote -v
origin  git@https://github.com/me/repo (fetch)
origin  git@https://github.com/me/repo (push)
```

How should I change git@https to enable git push?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls

Comment: Note that besides the standard `git remote set-url`, you can run `git config --edit` to just run your favorite editor on your `.git/config` file. I like to use this method myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? I haven´t seen the `git@...` never, I don´t know if this its the solution but it´s the first thing I would try.

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/me/repo.git`